# Connecting to Android via Appium Server on different network

Tags: networking, appium-android

I am trying to connect my Android devices present on a different network than my Appium Server but having no success.

P.S. The adb connects with the device over the same network and over USB but not to devices on a different network.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to get the IP address of the remote machine, your device is connected to. Assuming adb default port is 5555 and it is **exposed** to another machine with Appium server:

On machine with Appium server you run `adb connect <ip_address>:5555`, then `adb devices` should list remote device.

To have a robust solution you can have a look at OSS libraries like [OpenSTF](https://openstf.io/)